# Create-react-app and react-css-modules

Tags: webpack, configuration, connect, create-react-app, react-css-modules

Have anyone tried connect create-react-app with react-css-modules? I can't manage to configure webpack properly. Any help? Sharing webpack configuration will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

with create-react-app css modules are included. you just need to name your file for ex. style.modules.css, that way it is scoped to whatever file you want, if you don't include .modules it won't be properly scoped.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [patch-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-styles). It seems to be much easier and has a similar effect.